# Setting a variable to have the same value of a property

Tags: css

I'm using CSS to format a div whose height changes every time that the page is reloaded.

I want to write a CSS animation that scrolls through that CSS over a set amount of time.

I think I'm close to it, but I'm having an hard time putting the `height` value inside of a variable.

My current attempt is this one:

```
#feed {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: scroll 10s linear;
    --feed-height: attr(height);
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        top: var(--feed-height);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

animating from `top:0` to `top:height_value` is almost equivalent to `translateY(100%)` So you can do:

```css
#feed {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: scroll 10s linear;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(100%); /* OR -100% to have the opposite animation */
  }
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well, even though I'd still prefer to use a variable because actually that MWE is a simplified version of a more complex code I'm working on, and I'd need the variable to make other calculations, so that I can precisely define where the div will stop to scroll.

Comment: @ilmietitore you can still do it inside the transform by using `calc(100% - X)` where X is a  pixel value and the 100% is your height